# duplicate records in my results

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

my model defines like this

```
class UserAppWeekStatistics(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'user_app_week_statistics'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
imei = db.Column(db.String(15), primary_key=True, index=True)
year = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,
                 default=int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')), index=True)
week = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,
                 default=int(datetime.now().strftime('%W')), index=True)
count = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<UserAppWeekStatistics %r-%r-%r>' % (self.imei, self.year, self.week)
```

and in my views

```
user_app_week_statistics = UserAppWeekStatistics.query.filter_by(imei=json_req['imei'],
                                                                 year=int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')),
                                                                 week=int(datetime.now().strftime('%W'))).first()
if user_app_week_statistics is None:
    user_app_week_statistics = UserAppWeekStatistics()
    user_app_week_statistics.imei = json_req['imei']
    user_app_week_statistics.count = 1
else:
    user_app_week_statistics.count += 1
db.session.add(user_app_week_statistics)
db.session.commit()
```

and bellow is capture my results in my database.
[image]

In my opinion, there would be just one record with same imei, year and week, but in my project there may be many duplicate records with same imei ,year and week. I am really confused.My database is mysql 5.6.

Comment: why You set primary key on every column?

Comment: I just want to make them as union primary key, it is allowed according to the doc.

Comment: Primary keys are allowed, but for SQL databases it's not correct. In Your code PK-s are created for each of column (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Fix Your model, there can be only 1 `primary_key`.

2) No need for `index` on every field, especially on statistics tables - it makes inserts, updates slower, cuz every time db engine does re-indexing.

3) add unique composite index to prevent duplications.

finally here is Your model:

```
class UserAppWeekStatistics(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'user_app_week_statistics'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  imei = db.Column(db.String(15), index=True)
  year = db.Column(db.Integer, default=int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')))
  week = db.Column(db.Integer, default=int(datetime.now().strftime('%W')))
  count = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

  # add this
  __table_args__ = db.UniqueConstraint('imei', 'year', 'week', name='uq_user_app_week_statistics_imei_year_week')

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<UserAppWeekStatistics %r-%r-%r>' % (self.imei, self.year, self.week)
```